# How to specify a cache validator in wordpress where I am using this code in my .htaccess file but still no changes

Tags: caching, https, http-headers

Header set Last-Modified "Tue, 31 Aug 2010 00:00:00 GMT"

Answer (score 0):

Could you add following code at the end of .htaccess?

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On 
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

I hope this will work for you.